# Launch container from webpage

Tags: docker, linux-containers

I have looked at sonata project demo page: http://demo.sonata-project.org

There is something wonderfull on this page: They can start a container from a webpage.
How can we do that ?
What i want to do too is to wait the container ready before redirecting to it.
And how can they automaticly delete the container after 10 minutes ?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can create a frontend API over docker commands as per your customization , in backend docker commands are only running so when you press start button it will run docker run command to start container and so on.. for removing the container you can easily filter docker containers on basis of timestamps : https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/#filtering.